# How to recognize the color of a license plate？

Tags: python, opencv

First you should to use this command to install hyperlpr:

```
pip install hyperlpr
```

Then I use this code to identify the license plate number.

```
from hyperlpr import *
import cv2 #opencv3.X version
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt

#BGR
COLORS = [
    (230, 131, 1),  # blue
    (112, 249, 90),  # green
    (5, 189, 252),  # yellow
    (72, 61, 60),  # black
    (251, 253, 252) # white
]

def closest_color(rgb):
    r, g, b = rgb
    color_diffs = []
    for color in COLORS:
        cr, cg, cb = color
        color_diff = sqrt(abs(r - cr)**2 + abs(g - cg)**2 + abs(b - cb)**2)
        color_diffs.append((color_diff, color))
    return min(color_diffs)[1]

image_list = [r"9.jpg","11.jpg"]

for name in image_list:
    image = cv2.imread(name)
    result_green = HyperLPR_plate_recognition(image)
    if result_green:
        number = result_green[0][0]
        confidence = result_green[0][1]
        left,top,right,bottom = result_green[0][2]
        rec = image[top:bottom,left:right]
        cv2.imshow(name,rec)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        blue_mean = np.mean(image[:,:,0])#blue_mean
        green_mean = np.mean(image[:,:,1])#green_mean
        red_mean = np.mean(image[:,:,2])#red_mean
        print(blue_mean,green_mean,red_mean)
        index = COLORS.index(closest_color((red_mean, green_mean, blue_mean)))
        print(index)#black
```

Whether it is a green license plate or a yellow license plate, the result after using the np.mean is black,so how to recognize the color of a license plate？

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you ever look at the distribution of the values in the three channels? What happens if you replace the mean by the median?

Comment: Yea, I'd discard any pixels below a certain threshhold, say `(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)`, possibly even highlighs as well, such as `(0.9, 0.9, 0.9)` then find an average color of the remaining midtones.  oh, is that RGB255?  `(30, 30 30)` for lows, `(245, 245, 245)` or so for highs.

Comment: So you can detect the where the plate is as coordinates ?

Comment: Thanks!I plan to use a neural network to do it. First try labelimg to label, and then use pytorch+yolov5 to train. I think the effect of neural network is better. Of course, the code to write has also increased.